# Access an application and instantiate an object

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an instance of a specific class called ExtraScreen from a referenced library application called EXTRA. How can I use the SendKeys function from the ExtraScreen class?

So far I tried this:

```
Dim software As EXTRA.ExtraScreen
software.SendKeys ("a")
```

The result is Error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: All you did is `Dim` it - you also have to `Set` it to something.

Comment: Im not sure what I have to set it equal to. When I try to set "software" as an EXTRA.Application object,  I get an error saying "Object variable or With block variable not set". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also `Set` it to something:

```
Dim software As EXTRA.ExtraScreen
Set software = CreateObject("EXTRA.ExtraScreen")
```

or

```
Dim software As New EXTRA.ExtraScreen
```

Comment: Note: `CreateObject` returns an `Object`, and its argument is a ProgID string (may be different than the `library.class` name) which is determined by the COM registration of the type you're instantiating. VBA will hit the registry to locate the registration for the given ProgID, then find the CLSID subkey for it, then locate the library, then load it and spawn an instance of the class you asked for, and then the `Object` is cast to its `ExtraScreen` interface upon assignment. Quite a lot of work for something that can simply be `New`'d up, given the code is obviously early-bound anyway.

Comment: Also note: `As New` creates an *auto-instantiated* object variable, which means the object can never really be destroyed - if it's ever set to `Nothing`, VBA will happily spawn a new instance as soon as it's referenced again. In other words, split `Dim` and `New` into two instructions, unless you absolutely *need* an auto-instantiated object... which is rather unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an object variable with a specific, early-bound type - which means if the code can compile & run, then the project has a reference to the type library.

> ```
> Dim software As EXTRA.ExtraScreen
> ```

`Dim` statements aren't executable: you can't put a breakpoint on a `Dim` statement. All they do is allocate a spot of a given size in memory. In this case, it reserves a spot wide enough to hold an object reference - *and nothing else*.

On execution, the first statement to execute is this:

> ```
> software.SendKeys ("a")
> ```

But the problem is, if you put a breakpoint here and inspect the *Locals* toolwindow, you'll find that the `software` object contains `Nothing`. In other languages this is known as a "null reference" - the object variable is *not set*: there's a reserved spot for holding an object reference, but the spot is empty.

You use the `New` keyword to *create an instance* of a class - i.e. to *create an object*. And in VBA object reference assignments require the `Set` keyword:

```
Set software = New EXTRA.ExtraScreen
```

Now if you run that line and inspect your *locals*, you'll find that `software` isn't `Nothing` anymore, and you can inspect its state / properties.

Once an object variable holds a proper object reference, you can legally invoke its members:

```
software.SendKeys "a"
```

You can never invoke anything on a `Nothing` object reference: an object variable that is `Nothing` *is, well, nothing*: it's not an object, therefore it has no members to invoke. VBA runtime responds by throwing run-time error 91 "Object (or With block variable) not Set".

The "With block variable" part is referring to the `With` keyword, which can also hold objects. For example you could do this:

```
With software
    .SendKeys "a"
End With
```

And you'd get the exact same error if `software` isn't `Set`. Consider dropping the local variable altogether, if it only ever needs to live as a local variable inside some specific procedure:

```
With New EXTRA.ExtraScreen
    .SendKeys "a"
End With
```

In this case the `With` block is holding the object reference; at `End With`, the object is gone (avoid jumping in & out of `With` blocks, specifically for that reason).

Comment: i tried to set the object reference using the New keyword as well as the CreateObject function, but I am still unable to set the reference. i think the reason it is not working is because the software is a virtual application and not a local application based off this hyper link from Microsoft.    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications

Comment: What the heck is a *virtual application*? If the library you're trying to access isn't on your system,*of course* it's not going to work. Late binding isn't magic! I was assuming your code compiles.

Comment: The library is on my system and i added it as a reference. Strangley enough when i use the syntax to declare the object, autocompletion for the objects property and methods are availabe. So i know the referenced library is correct. The application I am using is an application at my job. Basically, a virtual app is an app is an app that is not installed on your device. Check out this link explaining it below. Basically i can use any computer in my company and access the application, even though it is not installed on the specific computer i use. https://www.parallels.com/blogs/ras/virtual-app/

Comment: At the end of the day VBA understands COM. If it's referenced and you get IntelliSense then there's no use for `CreateObject`. Do you get IntelliSense/autocomplete after typing `New`? Alt+D,ENTER to explicitly compiles the project; if that doesn't spawn an error box, then everything *should* work. Try `Set a = New EXTRA.ExtraScreen` in the *immediate* toolwindow (Ctrl+G), do you get an error? What does `?a Is Nothing` print then? If it's `False`, `?TypeName(a)` should be `ExtraScreen`. How far does it let you get?

Comment: I think you should edit your question with more details about what you've tried and what errors you're getting in what circumstances - RTE429 is *normally* a solved problem, so without all the info you get the trivial answers... Have you tried early/late binding with the library locally registered, to eliminate the virtualisation as a part of the problem? If it won't work under "normal use", the problem could be with the library instead. OP involves a misleading RTE91..

Comment: I do get IntelliSense after typing New, but I cant compile the object. When i do Set a = New EXTRA.ExtraScreen in the immediate toolwindow, i get RTE429. I also get the same thing for set a = New ExtraScreen, early and late binding.